# Native looking tabs for android with Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic app for both iOS and Android. I have a view which on iOS have the tabs on the bottom with icons and text under. On Android Ionic takes care of placing the tabs on the top but I don't want any icons, basically I want to achieve a native look for android also, like in this picture:

http://ionicframework.com/img/blog/lab.png

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the native look on android shown on your picture, you will need to add manually the tabs on top. Remember that is the same code and css for both iOS and Android, it will not change automatically. Here you can find what you want:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#striped-style-tabs